# How to add password to smtp settings without comprimizing account security

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set up an email contact form on my Rails app, but I am having trouble figuring out how to get the settings in config/production to read my password, without comprising my account.

Here are a heroku configs:

```
Jillians-MacBook-Pro-2:noises3 Jillian$ heroku config
=== noises Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:             xxxdatabaseurlxxx
LANG:                     en_US.UTF-8
RACK_ENV:                 production
RAILS_ENV:                production
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: enabled
S3_BUCKET:                muzack
SECRET_KEY_BASE:          xxxsecretxxx
gmail_password:           xxxmy_passwordxxx
gmail_username:           xxxmy_emailxxx
```

And my smtp settings, in config/production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            ENV['gmail_username'],
    password:             ENV['gmail_password'],
    authentication:       :plain
  }
```

And in config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "gmail.com",
    :user_name => "jho3292@gmail.com",
    :password => WHAT DO I DO HERE???
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this correctly?

Comment: Why are you setting the smtp settings twice?

Comment: I think Fred is right. You should not need the config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb. Your smtp settings are coming from the config.action_mailer.smtp_settings in config/production.rb